# Invalid access token when fetch the recent post with Instagram?

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, instagram

I have developed a program to fetch the latest post from a specific user account in PHP,

recently the fetch path no longer works and return:

```
{"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "code": 400, "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}}
```

The API used is:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=test&client_id=1111111

Any idea to fix it? Thanks a lot for helping

**Updated:**

it is caused by this API needs access token now:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/11111/media/recent?client_id=11111&count=10

it caused a problem as I prefer the visitor can see the content without login

Comment: Your token may have expired. Get a new token, preferentially one that not expires.

Comment: thanks. would you mind explain a bit more detail? Because in the old times I can call the url directly and it returns data

Comment: I'd take a look here -> https://www.sitepoint.com/conquering-instagram-with-php-and-the-instagram-api/

Comment: is recently some changes,  as their API console no longer exist, https://www.instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: It's deprecated, use it at https://apigee.com/console/instagram

Comment: thanks, is that means every API now need to implement the oauth 2 recently? As I remember no auth need to get the public content before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid implement oauth , you can use this feed:

```
https://www.instagram.com/{user-name}/media/
```

Since in my case is Ajax, I have to create a php for same domain policy:

```
<?= file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/{user-name}/media/'); ?>
```

Hope they won't close this feed as I prefer the user can read the content without login